# acts_as_taggable_on: query for users tagged with any of these tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using [acts_as_taggable_on](http://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and I'm trying to query for all users tagged with **any** of the tags in the collection `tags`

Right now I'm doing:

```
tags.map(&:name).each { |name| @result.push User.tagged_with(name) }
```

Is there a way that I can do this in one query, and not `tags.size` queries? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
User.tagged_with(tags.map(&:name), :any => true)
```

Hope it helps!